# Grails gorm catch foreign key constraint error

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In Grails i want to catch the exception when foreign key constraint appears, this is my code

```
    try {
        instance.delete(flush:true)
        flash.message = message(code : "default.deleted.message", args : [instance])
        flash.level = "info"
    } catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException | Exception e) {
        flash.message =  message(code : "default.not.deleted.message", args :  [instance])
        flash.level = "danger"
    }
```

The problem is when there is a foreign key constraint, it never enters the catch block.
Any idea what exception i should add ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `grails 2.3.5` and following code works for me

```
try {
    user.delete(flush: true)
    render "OK"
} catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    render "DataIntegrityViolationException"
} catch (Throwable v) {
    render "Throwable"
}
```

Try this..,.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because [MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html?is-external=true) is thrown on `update` or `insert` not `delete`

```
Exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an
 integrity constraint. Note that this is not purely a relational concept; unique primary
 keys are required by most database types.
```

Try with `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`

**EDIT**

Which version of **Grails** are you using ?

I found this issue [GRAILS-9357](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9357)

Comment: Yes ..this the issue in on jirra you will never get the chance to cache this exception its a bug..